Observer Zookeeper node is not reachable after appling the re-config command for changing to observer
We have tried to change one of the zookeeper node out of 6 to observer. After executing the re-config command the observer node is not reachable. It is only occurring in production cluster and not occurring in a test cluster with same configuration. Have anyone faced this issue?
refer the command,
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 reconfig -members server.1=kafka1:2888:3888:participant,server.2=kafka2:2888:3888:participant,server.3=kafka3:2888:3888:participant,server.4=kafka4:2888:3888:participant,server.5=kafka5:2888:3888:observer,server.6=kafka6:2888:3888:participant
I would like find the reason of this problem and a solution if required
